# How to add predefined and custom ckeditor plugins to ng2-ckeditor

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am trying to add the stylesheetparser plugin to the ng2-ckeditor module on inline mode of ckeditor in angular2. But i am getting the output in the styles dropdown with an right square bracket and also the "Source" button in ckeditor is missing.

eg: div.editable]

I am using the following codes to add the plugin,

**CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';**

CDN version of ckeditor used is **"https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full-all/ckeditor.js"**

Please help me to find a solution for it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Add this code is html and ts file. Hope so it will work fine.

**Component.ts**

```
ckeConfig : any;
this.ckeConfig = {
   height: 500,
   width: '60%',
   allowedContent: false,
   fullPage : true,
   toolbar: [
       { name: "styles", items: ['Format', 'Font', 'FontSize', "-", "TextColor", "BGColor"] },
       { name: "basicstyles", items: ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "RemoveFormat"] },
       "/",
       { name: "justify", items: ["JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock"] },
       { name: "paragraph", items: ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "-", "Blockquote"] },
       { name: "links", items: ["Link", "Unlink"] },
       { name: "insert", items: ["Image", "Table", "HorizontalRule", "Smiley","SpecialChar"] },
       { name: "document", items: ["Source"] },
   ]
 };
```

**Component.html :-**

```
<ckeditor [config]="ckeConfig" ></ckeditor>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Harleen. Actually i got the ckeditor structure properly but my question is regarding the stylesheet parser plugins output where i am getting an right square bracket along with the element as i mentioned in the example above .

Comment: this does not answer the question.